# How To Get Type Info Without Using Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, typeinfo

I have an `object obj` that is passed into a helper method.

```
public static MyTagGenerateTag<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, T obj /*, ... */)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in t.GetProperties())
    {
        object propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        string stringValue = propValue.ToString();
        dictionary.Add(prop.Name, stringValue);
    }

    // implement GenerateTag
}
```

I've been told this is not a correct use of generics. Can somebody tell me if I can achieve the same result without specifying a generic type? If so, how?

I would probably change the signature so it'd be like:

```
public static MyTag GenerateTag(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj /*, ... */)
{
    Type t = typeof(obj);
    // implement GenerateTag
}
```

but `Type t = typeof(obj);` is impossible.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: What was the reasoning behind it not being a correct use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Type t = obj.GetType();`

Although I don't think there's any problem with what you have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

What about just doing:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
```

That should give you the TypeInfo.